# Set border in word automaticly

Tags: microsoft-word

How do you set microsoft word so that when you paste a picture / photo from a folder to a word doc, it automatically borders it with black line with X weight, without the hassle of right clicking it then click on the Colors and Lines Tab and selecting black in the color field under the Line sub title. I'm using microsoft 2016.

Comment: record a macro and replay it whenever you want to paste

Comment: Does that trick still needs to click another extra button (other than ctrl+v)  every time we paste a pic into doc? Is there a more automated way ? I mean just using ctrl +v it automatically borders it for us every time we paste a pic / photo. U know  same way like when we define whether a pic pasted into doc will be pasted as thight, square, in front of text, etc

Comment: You can assign a keyboard shortcut to your macro. You can include the paste in your macro and use that instead of Ctrl+V. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330

Comment: Is there no way to make it as a default thing that would happen when you paste (ctrl + v) a pic in doc?

Comment: no, it's too specific so just set a custom shortcut for that specific task. Ctrl+V is a general paste only